# How to fix "expected token ',', got 'invalid'" eroor in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to throw every error which is done by the user while filling up the form.

I have tried putting a comma here and there but nothing seems to be working

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/app.py", line 14, in index
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/templates/form.html", line 39, in template
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1005, in render
    return concat(self.root_render_func(self.new_context(vars)))
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/templates/index.html", line 3, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'layout.html' %}
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/templates/layout.html", line 21, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/templates/index.html", line 115, in block "content"
    {% include 'form.html' %}
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/templates/form.html", line 39, in template
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 497, in _parse
    return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 901, in parse
    result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 883, in subparse
    rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
    return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 213, in parse_if
    'name:endif'))
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
    result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 875, in subparse
    add_data(self.parse_tuple(with_condexpr=True))
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 620, in parse_tuple
    args.append(parse())
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 432, in parse_expression
    return self.parse_condexpr()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 437, in parse_condexpr
    expr1 = self.parse_or()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 450, in parse_or
    left = self.parse_and()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 459, in parse_and
    left = self.parse_not()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 470, in parse_not
    return self.parse_compare()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 474, in parse_compare
    expr = self.parse_math1()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 496, in parse_math1
    left = self.parse_concat()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 507, in parse_concat
    args = [self.parse_math2()]
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 517, in parse_math2
    left = self.parse_pow()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 528, in parse_pow
    left = self.parse_unary()
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 547, in parse_unary
    node = self.parse_postfix(node)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 676, in parse_postfix
    node = self.parse_call(node)
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 767, in parse_call
    self.stream.expect('comma')
  File "/home/bhuvan/Documents/seriously_portfolio/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py", line 384, in expect
    self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'invalid'
```

'''

form.html

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.name.label() }}

        {% if form.name.errors %}
            {{ form.name(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ form.name(class="form-control") }}
            <!-- <small class="form-text text-muted">
                Enter Characters between 5-20.
            </small> -->
        {% endif %} 

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email.label() }}
        {% if form.email.errors %}
            {{ form.email(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ form.email(class="form-control") }}
        {% endif %} 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.message.label() }}
        <!-- {{ form.message(class="form-control", rows="4", cols="50", placeholder="Enter your message...") }} -->
        {% if form.message.errors %}
            {{ form.message(class="form-control is-invalid) }}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.message.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ form.message(class="form-control") }}
            <!-- <small class="form-text text-muted">
                Optional. Max Characters 300 only.
            </small> -->
        {% endif %} 
    </div>          
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info")}}
    </div>
</form>
```

Edit: I'm just writing random things to get the post submitted. Please ignore this thing. Nope it still wont submit help goddamnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing `"`:

```
{{ form.message(class="form-control is-invalid) }}
```